# How to create a custom streaming data source?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a custom reader for Spark Streaming that reads data from WebSocket. I'm going to try Spark Structured Streaming.

How to create a streaming data source in Spark Structured Streaming?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A streaming data source implements [org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.Source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Source.scala).

The scaladoc of `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.Source` should give you enough information to get started (just follow the types to develop a compilable Scala type).

Once you have the `Source` you have to register it so you can use it in `format` of a `DataStreamReader`. The trick to make the streaming source available so you can use it for `format` is to register it by creating the `DataSourceRegister` for the streaming source. You can find examples in [META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister):

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSinkProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.TextSocketSourceProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.RateSourceProvider
```

That's the file that links the short name in `format` to the implementation.

What I usually recommend people doing during my Spark workshops is to start development from both sides:

1. Write the streaming query (with `format`), e.g.

   ```
   val input = spark
     .readStream
     .format("yourCustomSource") // <-- your custom source here
     .load
   ```
2. Implement the streaming `Source` and a corresponding `DataSourceRegister` (it could be the same class)
3. (optional) Register the `DataSourceRegister` by writing the fully-qualified class name, say `com.mycompany.spark.MyDataSourceRegister`, to `META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister`:

   ```
   $ cat META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister
   com.mycompany.spark.MyDataSourceRegister
   ```

The last step where you register the `DataSourceRegister` implementation for your custom `Source` is optional and is only to register the data source alias that your end users use in [DataFrameReader.format](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@format(source:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) method.

> **format(source: String): DataFrameReader**
>   Specifies the input data source format.

Review the code of [org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.RateSourceProvider](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/RateSourceProvider.scala) for a good head start.

Comment: Where is `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSource` registered?

Comment: @lfk Added more explanation on the registration step. Let me know if it's still unclear. Thanks.

Comment: `TextFileFormat` for instance implements `DataSourceRegister`, but not `Source`. The actual `Source` is created by `DataSource.createSource` and it's `FileStreamSource` for all instances of `FileFormat` (DataSource.scala line 265, spark-sql_2.11). I can implement `DataSourceRegister`, but I still don't understand how I can use a custom `Source` instance.

Comment: Why do you think that `TextFileFormat` is responsible for streaming Datasets for text files? It is only used for batch/non-streaming Datasets. Look at `FileStreamSource` (and `DataSource.createSource` that registers it). Why don't you implement `Source` with `DataSourceRegister`?

Comment: I tried implementing `Source` and `DataSourceRegister`. The code fails with `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source test does not support streamed reading`. 
Check `DataSource.scala:275`. It needs to implement `StreamSourceProvider` not `Source`. That is of course for V1. V2 data sources follow a different code path.

Answer (score 14):

As Spark is moving to the V2 API, you now have to implement [DataSourceV2](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/spark-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT-2017_12_08_20_01-acf7ef3-docs/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/DataSourceV2.html), [MicroBatchReadSupport](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/MicroBatchReadSupport.html), and [DataSourceRegister](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/MicroBatchReadSupport.html).

This will involve creating your own implementation of `Offset`, `MicroBatchReader`, `DataReader<Row>`, and `DataReaderFactory<Row>`.

There are some [examples](https://github.com/hienluu/wikiedit-streaming) of custom structured streaming examples online (in Scala) which were helpful to me in writing mine.

Once you've implemented your custom source, you can follow Jacek Laskowski's answer in registering the source.

Also, depending on the encoding of messages you'll receive from the socket, you may be able to just use the default socket source and use a custom map function to parse the information into whatever Beans you'll be using. Although do note that Spark says that the default socket streaming source shouldn't be used in production!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

As Spark 3.0 introduced some major changes to the data source API, here is an updated version:

A class named `DefaultSource` extending `TableProvider` is the entry-point for the API. The `getTable` method returns a table class extending `SupportsRead`. This class has to provide a `ScanBuilder` as well as define the sources capabilities, in this case `TableCapability.MICRO_BATCH_READ`.

The `ScanBuilder` creates a class extending `Scan` that has to implement the `toMicroBatchStream` method (for a non-streaming use case we would implement the `toBatch` method instead). `toMicroBatchStream` now returns as class extending `MicroBatchStream` which implements the logic of what data is available and how to partition it ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/read/streaming/MicroBatchStream.html)).

Now the only thing left is a `PartitionReaderFactory` that creates a `PartitionReader` responsible for actually reading a partition of the data with `get` returning the rows one by one. You can use `InternalRow.fromSeq(List(1,2,3))` to convert the data to an `InternalRow`.

I created a minimal example project: [here](https://github.com/DeDa01/spark-streaming-example)

Comment: do you have some comprehensive code example to share? snippets are enough, I do not have a clue how to actually put this together.

Comment: I added an example project to the answer

Comment: great stuff! thanks a lot. How do you actually register it? I see that you did ".format(Some.class.getPackageName()) but that does not make a lot of sense to me as there is no reference to it in the implementation. Is not there any resorce file to put that implementation in? How does this work? Differently than in Spark 2.x?

Comment: Ok I checked it in Spark source code and it loads DefaultSource if load method is fed with package name - it will load packageName + "DefaultSource".

Comment: @Derda: would it makes sense to implement such a thing around `alpakka-kafka` sources?  For example `committablePartitionedSource` wraps kafka anyway. See more https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/consumer.html. The rationale being to dcouple spark-streaming from kafka for more flexibility in design of data flow orchestration.

Answer (score 2):

Also [Here](https://github.com/fdeantoni/spark-websocket-datasource) is a sample implementation for a custom WebSocket Stream Reader/Writer which implements `Offset, MicroBatchReader, DataReader<Row>`, and `DataReaderFactory<Row>`