# unzip a zipped file on Azure databricks file system

Tags: python, databricks

I would like to unzip a tgz file located on azure databricks file system.

```
 display(dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/my_data/MY_zipfile.tgz"))
```

I can see the file but how I can unzip it ?

It is an application file and I need to unzip it and compile it.

I tried this in databricks notebook:

```
  %sh
  unzip dbfs:/my_data/MY_zipfile.tgz
```

but, the file cannot be found.

It seems that the shell cannot access it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can unzip tgz file . You can read this if you want to implement something of your own .
[How to load tar.gz files in streaming datasets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034069/how-to-load-tar-gz-files-in-streaming-datasets)